# Is it possible to force rmarkdown use "html" instead of "html4"?

Tags: html, r-markdown, pandoc

It is hardcoded in [pandoc.R](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/pandoc.R) by some reasons (unknown for me). I tried to specify html5 in YAML section:

```
---
title: "My title"
date: "`r Sys.time()`"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_width: 8
    fig_height: 6
    toc: true
    theme: null
    mathjax: null
    highlight: "pygments"
    md_extensions: -autolink_bare_uris
    self_contained: FALSE
    template: journal.html5
    pandoc_args: ["--to=html"]
---
```

but when I render it (by `rmarkdown::render("file.rmd")`, I **don't** use RStudio), console output looks like:

```
/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS table_to_graph.utf8.md --to html4 --from 
markdown+tex_math_single_backslash-autolink_bare_uris+smart --output file.html
--email-obfuscation none --to=html --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents
--toc-depth 3 --template journal.html5 
--highlight-style pygments --lua-filter
```

You can see both arguments. The goal is to have just `--to html`. When I put `-t html` in YAML, I'm getting an error:

```
Unknown writer:  html
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
```

In [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) there are variants `--to=html` and `-t html`.
So for now I have to manually patch the `pandoc.R` file every rmarkdown update (quite often). If anybody knows how to force html(5) via YAML please answer.

**Update: pandoc info**

```bash
$ pandoc -v
pandoc 2.7.3
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.5.4, texmath 0.11.2.2, skylighting 0.8.1
Default user data directory: /home/***/.local/share/pandoc or /home/***/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2019 John MacFarlane
Web:  http://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness
for a particular purpose.
$ eix -I pandoc
[I] app-text/pandoc-bin [1]
     Доступные версии:      2.6^m 2.7.3^p
     Установленные версии:  2.7.3^p(10:40:08 13.11.2019)
     Домашняя страница:     https://pandoc.org https://github.com/jgm/pandoc
     Описание:              An universal document converter

[1] "local_overlay" /usr/local/portage
```

Comment: maybe you have a really old pandoc version?

Comment: Not so old, pandoc-2.7.3, and update R packages daily.

Comment: Are you sure it's calling your pandoc 2.7 ? In that I think the error would be `Unknown output format`, not `Unknown writer`...

Comment: try `pandoc -t html table_to_graph.utf8.md` (I'm guessing this will work, since it's calling pandoc 2.7.3). But your R function might be calling a different (older) pandoc binary.